# Java: как передать логин в сессии?

Tags: веб-программирование, java

Есть сервлет

```
 HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession(true); 
 String Login = (String) request.getParameter("login");
 httpSession.setAttribute("login", Login);
 response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

И есть jsp страница

```
String username=(String) session.getAttribute("login");  
if(username==null)  
username="";

 <p>Добро пожаловать, <%=username%></p>
```

Не передает логин в сессии. В чем тут ошибка?

Comment: директива page на странице есть?

Comment: Да,в самом начале

    <%@ page  
    language="java"  
    contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"  
    pageEncoding="utf-8"  
    %>

Comment: попробуйте добавить к этой директиве атрибут session="true"

Comment: Не помогло(

Comment: Как вызывается сервлет? Уверены, что параметр login в него передается и приходит?

Comment: Да,я даже пробовал передавать данные не с формы,а просто  с заранее отправленных переменных

Comment: Попробуйте вместо:

    String username=(String) session.getAttribute("login");  
    if(username==null)  
    username="";

     <p>Добро пожаловать, <%=username%></p>

сделать так: `<p>Добро пожаловать, ${username}></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.sendRedirect()` передает управление браузеру, чтобы он сделал перенаправление на страницу - трудно ожидать при этом что сессия сохранится...

Надо делать перенаправление через контекст сервера - типа `pageContext.forward()` или как указал [@SergioVasus](/users/10588/sergiovasus) (что суть одно и то же)

Answer (score 3):

Похоже на то, что ты делаешь просто редирект на страницу "index.jsp". Для передачи данных попробуй:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response)
```