# Передача русских символов в запросе при response.sendRedirect(url)

Tags: java, кодировка, jsp, redirect, параметры

Проблема заключается в следующем. Есть две странички - main.jsp и books.jsp и форма поиска. При поиске с books (метод GET) все отлично. При поиске с main (если в url пришел параметр search_str) я делаю `response.sendRedirect(String url)` на books, задавая в строке адрес и параметры поиска, которые пришли в запросе. Но по итогу в books.jsp приходит параметр не, к примеру, "books.jsp?search_str=**смит**", а "books.jsp?search_str=**A<8B**". То есть русские символы приходят в другой кодировке.

```
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>
<%response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>
```

не помогло. Что сделать для правильной передачи параметров при редиректе?

Comment: Попробуйте так:   `response.sendRedirect(java.net.URLEncoder.encode("index?name=Русский язык"));` Взял [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10995843/6752984)

Comment: не прошло, но, подозреваю, что я как-то не так прописывал адрес. ну и плюс метод deprecated. а вот почти синхронно с Вами я наткнулся на решение своей проблемы [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/179078/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8). помог редирект через диспатчер `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pages/books.jsp").forward(request,response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помог редирект через диспатчер `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/pages/books.jsp")‌​.forward(request,res‌​ponse);`